# Replay a sound using EvalSound before the sound is ended

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script>
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
}
</script>

<embed src="success.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="sound1"
enablejavascript="true">
```

I play this sound when a function is triggered, with this javascript code. My code looks like this:

```
-function code-
pA = false;
EvalSound('sound1');
} else {
-more code-
```

This all works, but if triggers again before the sound is done playing, it will do nothing. I want it to replay the sound immediately when the function is triggered again, even if the sound isn't ended yet.

Tried `EvalSoundOff` but no luck with that one

Hope this is possible, all suggestions are welcome thanks!!

Comment: Please learn the difference between JavaScript & Java!  JavaSound is part of Java, not JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `thissound.Rewind();` above `thissound.Play();` worked for me!